# Get specific values from BeautifulSoup Parsing

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have recently started to learn more about Python and how to Parse websites using BeautifulSoup.

The problem I now face is that I seem to be stuck.

HTML Code (after taken by soup):

```
<div class="mod-3-piece-app__visual-container__chart">
    <div class="mod-ui-chart--dynamic" data-chart-config='{"chartData":{"periods":[{"year":2013,"period":null,"periodicity":"A","icon":null},{"year":2014,"period":null,"periodicity":"A","icon":null},{"year":2015,"period":null,"periodicity":"A","icon":null},{"year":2016,"period":null,"periodicity":"A","icon":null},{"year":2017,"period":null,"periodicity":"A","icon":null},{"year":2018,"period":null,"periodicity":"A","icon":null}],"forecastRange":{"from":3.5,"to":5.5},"actualValues":[5.6785,6.45,9.22,8.31,null,null],"consensusData":[{"y":5.6307,"toolTipData":{"low":5.5742,"high":5.7142,"analysts":34,"restatement":null}},{"y":6.3434,"toolTipData":{"low":6.25,"high":6.5714,"analysts":35,"restatement":null}},{"y":9.1265,"toolTipData":{"low":9.02,"high":9.28,"analysts":40,"restatement":null}},{"y":8.2734,"toolTipData":{"low":8.17,"high":8.335,"analysts":40,"restatement":null}},{"y":8.9304,"toolTipData":{"low":8.53,"high":9.63,"analysts":41,"restatement":null}},{"y":10.1252,"toolTipData":{"low":8.63,"high":11.61,"analysts":42,"restatement":null}}]}}'>
        <noscript>
            <div class="mod-ui-chart--static">
                <div class="mod-ui-chart--sprited" style="width:410px; height:135px; background:url('/data/Charts/EquityForecast?issueID=36276&amp;height=135&amp;width=410') 0px -270px no-repeat;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


data = []
List = ['AAPL']

# Iterates Through List
for i in List :   
    # The webpage which we wish to Parse
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/forecasts?s=AAPL:NSQ').read(), 'lxml')

    # Gathering the data
    Values = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"mod-3-piece-app__visual-container__chart"})[4]
    print(Values)

    # Getting desired values from data
```

What I wish to attain is the values after `{"y" ....,` hence the numbers `5.6307,6.3434,9.1265, 8.2734, 8.9304 and 10.1252` but I can't for the life of me figure out how. I have tried `Values.get_text` as well as `Values.text` but this just gives blank (probably because all of the code is inside a list or something similar).

If I could just get the data after "toolTipData" that would be fine as well.

Is there anyone that mind helping me out?

If I've missed anything please provide feedback so I can make a better question in the future.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, you want to get some info that is located inside an attribute tag.

All I had to do was:

1. open the web page source to understand where's located your info
2. use `find_all` looking for the right class attribute `mod-ui-chart--dynamic`
3. for each element located using `find_all`, fetch it's attribute content using `.get()`
4. search inside the attribute content string for the term `'actualValues'`
5. if found `'actualValues'`, then load json and navigate through it's values.

Try the following piece of code. I've commented it, so you should be able to understand what it's doing.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import json

data = []
List = ['AAPL']

# Iterates Through List
for i in List:   
    # The webpage which we wish to Parse
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/forecasts?s=AAPL:NSQ').read(), 'lxml')

    # Gathering the data
    elemList = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'mod-ui-chart--dynamic'})

    #we will get the attribute info of each `data-chart-config` tag, inside each `div` with `class=mod-ui-chart--dynamic`
    for elem in elemList:

        elemID = elem.get('class')
        elemName = elem.get('data-chart-config')

        #if there's no value in elemName, pass...
        if elemName is None:
            pass

        #if the term 'actualValues' exists in elemName 
        elif 'actualValues' in elemName:
            #print('Extracting actualValues from:\n')
            #print("Attribute id = %s" % elemID)
            #print()
            #print("Attribute name = %s" % elemName)
            #print()

            #reading `data-chart-config` attribute as a json
            data = json.loads(elemName)

            #print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            #print(data['chartData']['actualValues'])

            #fetching desired info
            val1 = data['chartData']['actualValues'][0]
            val2 = data['chartData']['actualValues'][1]
            val3 = data['chartData']['actualValues'][2]
            val4 = data['chartData']['actualValues'][3]

            #printing desired values
            print(val1, val2, val3, val4)

            print('-'*15)
```

**Output:**

```
1.9 1.42 1.67 3.36
---------------
5.6785 6.45 9.22 8.31
---------------
50557000000 42358000000 46852000000 78351000000
---------------
170910000000 182795000000 233715000000 215639000000
---------------
```

**p.s.1:** if you want, you can uncomment the `print()` functions inside the `elif loop` to understand the program.

**p.s.2:** if you want, you can change the `'actualValues'` at `val1 = data['chartData']['actualValues'][0]` to `'consensusData'`

Comment: Thank you, This works perfectly for 1 asset case (only AAPL) but as soon as I try to incorporate other assets (IBM for example)  val1-val4 get oversaved. I will try my best alone to find a way to split this dictionary into a list and then just append to it for each run.